# React Native status bar semi transparent

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-props, statusbar

Is it possible to make `StatusBar` semi-transparent with an opacity of 0.8?
if I pass backgroundColor={"transparent"} like in the docs it becomes fully transparent without color. Docs https://reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar

```
<StatusBar style="light" backgroundColor={"red"} translucent />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i did it. Under `StatusBar` added a View with `height: insets.top` and style for `StatusBar`. This works for both OS platforms.

```
return (
<View>
<StatusBar style="light" translucent />
<View style={[styles.statusBar, { height: insets.top }]}></View>
<View
    style={[
    styles.contentContainer,
    {
       paddingLeft: insets.left,
       paddingRight: insets.right,
    },
 ]} >

</View>
</View>
);
}
 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 statusBar: {
 opacity: 0.8,
 backgroundColor: "red",
 },       
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can give `backgroundColor` as `#FF000080`, and you can change color transparency by changing the last 2 digits of `#FF000080`

```js
<StatusBar style="light" backgroundColor={"#FF000080"} translucent />
```

Comment: If i set it like this the opacity looks different in the status bar than if i add same color on a container and set opacity : 0.8 to that container. The color on status bar color looks more transparent

Comment: add snack for your code

Comment: Then pass the same hex color to both the status bar and the container rather giving seperate opacity to it